# Show tooltip when the button isn't clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, tooltip

I want to show a tooltip when the user didn't click the specific button while submitting a form. I prevent the form from submitting and I want to show just the tooltip to say "you should click first the button". Thank's in advance.

```
<form id="signUpForm">
    <button type="button" id="agree" class="btn btn-default" data-color="info" tabindex="7">I Agree</button>
    <input type="hidden" id="hidden" value="0">
    <input type="submit" id="btn-submit" value="submit">
</form>

<script>
    $('#signUpForm').submit(function(e) {
        if ($('#hidden').val() == '0') {
            e.preventDefault();
            //show the tooltip that "you first click the agree button" and fadeOut(1000)
        }
    });
</script>
```

Comment: What tooltip? You've not shown it (or even the tooltip the library you're using) in the code.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan. I use tooltip bootstrap platform

Answer (score 0):

try this, make button type as button instead of submit:

```
<form id="signUpForm" >
 <button type="button" id="agree" class="btn btn-default" data-color="info" tabindex="7" >I Agree</button>
 <input type="hidden" id="hidden" value="0">
 <input type="button" id="btn-submit" value="submit">
</form>

 <script>
 $('#btn-submit').click(function(e){
   if($('#hidden').val()=='0'){

   }
   else {
      $('#signUpForm').submit();
   }
 });
 </script>
```

Comment: yes..because ad per my understanding - he want to prevent submit if hidden value is 0 and else submit..

Comment: His current logic is already doing that. The question is about adding a tooltip.

Answer (score 0):

Check below script it will helpful to you for display the tooltip.

```
<script>
    $(".tooltip").hide();
    $('#signUpForm').submit(function (e) {
        if ($('#hidden').val() == '0') {
            e.preventDefault();
            //show the tooltip that "you first click the agree button" and    fadeOut(1000)
            $("#signUpForm").find(".tooltip").stop().fadeIn();
            setTimeout(function () {
                $("#signUpForm").find(".tooltip").stop().fadeOut();
            }, 1000);
        }
    });
</script>
```

**HTML Part**

```
<form id="signUpForm">
    <button type="button" id="agree" class="btn btn-default" data-color="info" tabindex="7">I Agree</button>
    <input type="hidden" id="hidden" value="0">
    <input type="submit" id="btn-submit" value="submit">
    <div class="tooltip">
        you first click the agree button
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: it doesn't work.
to say more clear , I want sth like form validation which is check if the input has a value or not. if it hasn't , it shows text "you should fill this part" like tooltip

Comment: it must be work. Can you please tell me error which is displayed in console.

Comment: for that you need to manually check and display validation message.

Comment: first it has the functionality like submit btn and submit the form that I don't want it. Second, the div is visible at first load , I want it to be invisible at first, if the user submit the form and hasn't clicked the button , I will be appeared

Comment: for 1) you entered "e.preventDefault();" in your condition so page not submitted. 2)  "$(".tooltip").hide();" is added in script due to that initially div is hide.